# Set the Popup box to a fixed position

Tags: css, colorbox, fixed

I'm fairly new to HTML and CSS work but have been very proud of how far I've come with the help of forums like this one.  So first and foremost, thank you!

**My question**: I am using a Colorbox on my website that displays a popup on top of the current page.  The problem is, if I scroll with the mouse wheel and the pointer is resting in the grayed out area (the original page I opened the colorbox from), the original page scrolls down...thus eventually moving the colorbox off the screen.

What I want is for the colorbox to always be visible in the middle of the screen, regardless of how a user scrolls.  The only way to get rid of it would be to close it.

I've read a lot about using the position:fixed attribute, and have attempted to do that but had no success (tried surrounding the colorbox with a simple div with a "position: fixed" setting).   Plus in looking through various comments is seems like the fixed position is something that should be used sparingly, if at all.

Does anyone have a suggestion on a div I can create to keep the colorbox positioned on the screen at all times?  Or maybe an alternative idea, like preventing the ability for a user to scroll down the grayed out area of the original page?

Here's a [link](https://www.americasfootprints.com/sampleFootprint) to the page that displays the issue.  If you click on one of the dozens of sample story links, you'll see the colorbox appear.  When it does, start scrolling down the original page and you'll see the box eventually goes off the screen.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated everyone.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the Colorbox Javascript appends inline style to the box which will override external or internal CSS. Give your property values `!important` to prioritize.

```
#colorbox {
    outline: 0 none;
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 10% !important;
}
```

Comment: Manoj this was PERFECT and exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much for your help.  The only immediate issue I'm seeing is that this fix does not seem to work in Internet Explorer 11.  Looks good in Firefox and Chrome though.  Any suggestions for Explorer?

Comment: It seems to work in IE11 as well. Just checked from here. Try clearing the IE cache?

Comment: That cache thing gets me everytime lol.  Really appreciate it, and thanks for the tip.  Seems to work great!